# Function is not being called in the foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a class P_apps.vb

```
<Serializable()> _
<DefaultProperty("Items")> _
Public Class P_apps
    Inherits AbstractEntity

    Private mintID As Int32 = 0
    Private mstrStatus As String = ""
    Private mstrApplicationType As String = ""
    Private mstrLastName As String = ""
    Private mstrFirstName As String = ""
    Private mstrMiddleName As String = ""
    'other properties

     Private mstrItems As String = ""

Public Sub New(ByVal Items As String)
    mstrItems = Items
End Sub

Default Public Property Items(ByVal col As String) As String
    Get
        Return mstrItems
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mstrItems = value
    End Set
End Property

    'other properties
End Class
```

Then i have another partial class Online_apps.aspx.vb

```
Partial Public Class Online_apps
    Inherits BasePage
    Implements System.Collections.IComparer

    Dim mcolApps As New SBECollection(Of P_apps)

    'Some coding

    Dim _lstColumns As New List(Of String)

    Public Function Sortcompare(ByVal vobjPSA As Object, ByVal vobjPSB As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Dim intSortReturn As Integer = 0

        _lstColumns.ForEach(Function(rstrCol) Colsort(rstrCol, intSortReturn, CType(vobjPSA, P_apps), CType(vobjPSB, P_apps)))

    End Function

    Public Function Colsort(ByVal rstrCol As String, ByRef intSortReturn As Integer, ByVal vobjPSA As P_apps, ByVal vobjPSB As P_apps) As Integer
        If (intSortReturn = 0) Then
            If (vobjPSA(rstrCol) < vobjPSB(rstrCol)) Then
                intSortReturn = -1
            ElseIf (vobjPSA(rstrCol) > vobjPSB(rstrCol)) Then
                intSortReturn = 1
            End If
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Function GetP_apps() As SBECollection(Of P_apps)
           'Some coding
            mcolApps.ToList.Sort(AddressOf Sortcompare)
            Return mcolApps 
    End Function

End Class
```

I am calling the function GetP_apps() in my Page_Load in Online_apps

My SBECollection is define as

```
Public Class SBECollection(Of t As AbstractEntity)
      Inherits System.Collections.CollectionBase
      Member of SBEFramework
```

It is defined by my company

My ColSort function in my foreach loop in SortCompare is not being called.
And SortCompare is always being 0.

Can anyone help me with it

Comment: Where is the current instance of `P_apps` instantiated? How does its `Items` string get populated?

Comment: P_apps is instantiated in  P_apps class, I am sorry I did not put in here.  Items is populated in the Colsort function for vobjPSA and vobjPSB

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ thank you , I did not properly call the instance of P_apps. Now I am having a different problem.